# ESLint friendly way of resetting a wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, eslint

I have this code:

```
let wrapper;
const checkAnswerMock = jest.fn();
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(
    <CheckButton
      wasAnswerChecked={true}
      isAufgabeCompleted={true}
      handleClick={checkAnswerMock}
    />,
  );
});

it('should call checkAnswerMock onClick',
  () => {
    wrapper.find(CheckButtonElementGray).simulate('click');
    expect(checkAnswerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

And this works. But ESLint says:

> 10:3  error  Unallowed use of `let`. Use `const` instead  fp/no-let
>
> 13:5  error  Unallowed reassignment                       fp/no-mutation

How can I do this in ESLint - friendly way? I have to use this configuration of ESLint. (Corporate policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ESLint configuration is the problem here.
`fp/no-let` explicitly forbids the use of *any* `let` statement.

`wrapper` has to be mutable, so you can choose for two keywords: `let` and `var`...

I'd suggest changing your ESLint configuration to allow `let`, as there's no real reason why *nothing* can be mutable.

Comment: I edited my question. My bad for not including it since the beginning

Comment: I re-wrote my answer.

Comment: I'm looking for the config right now. I'll pick as best when I make sure it fixes it

Comment: Do you know of any way to restructure the no-mutable rule so it makes sense?

Comment: That rule (`fp/no-mutation`) is basically the same as `fp/no-let`... I'd suggest disabling that as well.

Comment: Ok perfect! Thank you!